# matplotlib xkcd not working on mac

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I've small problem in visualizing matplotlib xkcd plots. 
By simply trying to execute the example found on [matplotlib.org](http://matplotlib.org/examples/showcase/xkcd.html).
When i execute xkcd.py the visualization of the plots does't work
and I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1084, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2092, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/lines.py", line 712, in draw
    drawFunc(renderer, gc, tpath, affine.frozen())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/lines.py", line 1067, in _draw_lines
    self._lineFunc(renderer, gc, path, trans)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/lines.py", line 1107, in _draw_solid
    renderer.draw_path(gc, path, trans)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/patheffects.py", line 115, in draw_path
    rgbFace)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/patheffects.py", line 217, in draw_path
    renderer.draw_path(gc, tpath, affine, rgbFace)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 58, in draw_path
    gc.draw_path(path, transform, linewidth, rgbFace)
AttributeError: 'GraphicsContextBase' object has no attribute 'draw_path'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1084, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2092, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1102, in draw
    tick.draw(renderer)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/axis.py", line 244, in draw
    self.tick1line.draw(renderer)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/lines.py", line 757, in draw
    rgbaFace)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/patheffects.py", line 127, in draw_markers
    **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 266, in draw_markers
    rgbFace)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/patheffects.py", line 115, in draw_path
    rgbFace)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/patheffects.py", line 217, in draw_path
    renderer.draw_path(gc, tpath, affine, rgbFace)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.x-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 58, in draw_path
    gc.draw_path(path, transform, linewidth, rgbFace)
AttributeError: 'GraphicsContextBase' object has no attribute 'draw_path'
```

While if I try to save these plots I get two perfect png files:

I really don't understand why !

Comment: Because the xkcd filter does not work with the macOSX backend.

Comment: I would suggest using one of the Agg based backend (QtAgg, TxAgg, WxAgg, GtkAgg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a commenter said, the macOSX backend isn't supported.  With Python 3.4 on OS X 10.10.1, TkAgg worked.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
```