# Matplotlib seeing new font but not applying it, xkcd mode

Tags: matplotlib, fonts

I'm trying to get Matplotlib's xkcd style to use the font designed for it, Humor Sans.

I'm getting Comic Sans instead, see pic [image]

Now, the point is about the correct font not getting recognised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663986/getting-xkcd-plots-using-matplotlib), I have removed the cache as per [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/07/10/XKCD-plots-in-matplotlib/) and as suggested in the same question. Basically what is suggested in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146780/how-to-get-xkcd-font-on-matplotlib).

I have even "forced" Matplotlib to regenerate the font cache as

```
f = matplotlib.font_manager.FontManager()
```

and looks like the desired font is there:

```
f.findfont("Humor Sans")
'/Users/myname/Library/Fonts/Humor-Sans.ttf'
```

So I don't get why the plot still shows Comic Sans? It has been obtained with code

```
plt.xkcd()  
plt.plot([i for i in range(10)], np.sin([i for i in range(10)])) 
plt.title('A sine wave') 
plt.show()
```

I even tried changing backend as per [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27204209/matplotlib-xkcd-not-working-on-mac), to no avail.

Comment: I think clearing the fontcache means deleting the fontList in you matplotlib [cache directory](https://matplotlib.org/faq/troubleshooting_faq.html#matplotlib-configuration-and-cache-directory-locations). Have you done that?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have, yes, checked where the cache dir is and run `rm ~/.matplotlib/fontList.cache`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to also clear the cached font_manager instance, as

```
rm ~/.matplotlib/fontList.py3k.cache
```